# Working Sample of Firebase Phone Authentication for Web?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

Did anyone manage to make the Firebase phone authentication work ? 
Docs is a little vague and mixed-up.

What have I tried?
The instructions here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth

Comment: for anyone looking into this: https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web?utm_campaign=featureoverview_education_auth_en_07-11-17&utm_source=Firebase&utm_medium=yt-desc

Comment: There is also a quickstart for this: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/tree/master/auth